# Add Message After Empty Fields with Array Names

Tags: jquery, arrays, forms

I don't typically use an array for naming multiple textareas or input fields, but for this case, doing so made the PHP session storage/loop much easier to store JSON.

However, doing so broke my error checking. I can't seem to correct it to add an error message `after()` the textarea any longer.

So, a basic setup:

```
<form>
   <textarea class="form-control required-field" id="answer0" name="answer[]"></textarea>
   <textarea class="form-control required-field" id="answer1" name="answer[]"></textarea>
   <textarea class="form-control required-field" id="answer2" name="answer[]"></textarea>
   <button class="form-submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I'm looking to add a `<span>` class after any `.required-field` that is blank with a simple jQuery click event, but I'm stuck on how to do it with the `id` instead of the name attribute.

The main problem I'm running into is checking if a span tag already exists, as it will duplicate it indefinitely.

```
 $('.form-submit').click(function() {
    let req = '<span class="required-text">This field is required</span>';
    $('.required-field').each(function() {
       if($(this).val() == '') {
           // add span tag after textarea
       } else {
           // remove span tag after textarea
       }
    });
 });
```

Any ideas would be very helpful. Thanks much.

Comment: Hm, that might be related to how you've written the code that sits in `// add span tag after textarea`

Comment: Actually, you're right. Wow, I've stared at this for way too long. All good now. Thank you!

Comment: No worries, I've added my suggestion as a formal answer now instead to make it easier to find for future readers.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my post to reflect your answer as well. Feel free to revert, if you think it will help make it clearer for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to remove all elements with the `required-text` class using `$(".required-text").remove()`, then let your loop add the required text spans back in:

```js
$('.form-submit').click(function() {
  $(".required-text").remove(); // Remove any previous required-text elements (loop below will add them back in for the elements that still need it).

  let req = '<span class="required-text">This field is required</span>';
  $('.required-field').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      $(this).after(req); // add span tag after textarea
    }
  });
});
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.required-text {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <textarea class="form-control required-field" id="answer0" name="answer[]"></textarea>
  <textarea class="form-control required-field" id="answer1" name="answer[]"></textarea>
  <textarea class="form-control required-field" id="answer2" name="answer[]"></textarea>
  <button type="button" class="form-submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```